# How to select data in a particular order in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a way to select a row of data over other rows.  For instance, if I have the following data:

```
FIRSTNAME    LASTNAME  STARTDATE    ENDDATE       FLG_DT
JIM          SMITH     01-MAR-1987  09-OCT-2001    BEFORE
JIM          SMITH     05-MAY-2003  07-DEC-2007    MATCH
JIM          SMITH     01-APR-2009  01-DEC-2015    AFTER
JIM          SMITH     01-APR-2016  01-APR-2016    NONE
JOHN         SMITH     01-MAY-2002  01-MAR-2016    MATCH
LORI         SMITH     20-JAN-2009  20-JAN-2010    BEFORE
LORI         SMITH     21-JAN-2010  01-MAR-2016    AFTER
ADAM         TAYLOR    01-APR-2016  01-APR-2016    NONE
```

basically, for a distinct FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, STARTDATE I want to pick the row that has a FLG_DT = 'MATCH' first and only.  If 'MATCH' doesnt exist I want pick the row with  FLG_DT = 'BEFORE' next and only.  IF neither of those exist then I want to pick FLG_DT = 'AFTER'and if that doesnt exist then I'll take 'NONE.  I can use a ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION BY and ORDER BY the flg_dt field but not sure how to select it in this hierarchical order and leave the others out.  The results should be:

```
FIRSTNAME    LASTNAME  STARTDATE    ENDDATE       FLG_DT
JIM          SMITH     05-MAY-2003  07-DEC-2007    MATCH
JOHN         SMITH     01-MAY-2002  01-MAR-2016    MATCH
LORI         SMITH     20-JAN-2009  20-JAN-2010    BEFORE
ADAM         TAYLOR    01-APR-2016  01-APR-2016    NONE
```

Your help is appreciated.  I feel like this should be obvious to me but Im drawing a blank!

Answer (score 4):

This is a type of prioritization.  The simplest way is to use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by firstname, lastname, startdate
                                order by (case when flg_dt = 'MATCH' then 1
                                               when flg_dt = 'BEFORE' then 2
                                               when flg_dt = 'AFTER' then 3
                                               else 4
                                          end)
                                ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks..this works well.  I am stunned to see how this works because no matter what, the seqnum ends up being 1 so the 'THEN' doesnt really assign the value.. it just orders/prioritizes it as you mentioned, which makes the WHERE seqnum = 1 work.  Thats not at all how I thought that worked but now I see it.

Answer (score 0):

The data you show indicates that you really don't want it on DISTINCT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, STARTDATE - you only want the distinct FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME. Here's a modified version of @GordonLinoff's query which incorporates this change:

```
select t.*
from (select your_table.*,
             row_number() over (partition by firstname, lastname
                                order by (case when flg_dt = 'MATCH' then 1
                                               when flg_dt = 'BEFORE' then 2
                                               when flg_dt = 'AFTER' then 3
                                               else 4
                                          end)
                                ) as seqnum
      from your_table
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

and produces

```
FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    STARTDATE           ENDDATE             FLG_DT  SEQNUM
ADAM        TAYLOR      April, 01 2016      April, 01 2016      NONE    1
JIM         SMITH       May, 05 2003        December, 07 2007   MATCH   1
JOHN        SMITH       May, 01 2002        March, 01 2016      MATCH   1
LORI        SMITH       January, 20 2009    January, 20 2010    BEFORE  1
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4056/7)

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I do want the STARTDATE in the distinct as mentioned..its a rare case but it does happen occasionally.

Comment: OK, well - best of luck.